# How can I retrieve the hotness of a certain spot from the Google Maps HeatmapLayer?

Tags: google-maps, heatmap

I am currently fiddling around with Google Maps, I managed to create a map and feed some data points into it, by adding them to a HeatmapLayer object.
That generates a nice heatmap for me, but unfortunately I am interested in the temperature at a certain location on the map.
Does anyone have an idea on how to calculate/retrieve the hotness for a certain location on the map, based on the heatmap?

Thanks in advance & Best Regards

Comment: How are you calculating the 'temperature', is it by value (i.e. this point has a value of 100) or by density (i.e. there are 40 points within this area)? Also generally speaking the idea of a heatmap is to represent this kind of data visually. The 'temperature' should be easily inferred by the colour.

Comment: I am trying to get the density of points, but they are weighted, so they also have a certain value. I know that a heatmap is supposed to represent the information visually, but I want to evaluate the information programmatically, leaving me with the problem on how to do this. Thanks a lot! Cheers

Comment: So when you say you want the 'temperature' you want to know how google is working it out basically? Given that you have all of the information you have supplied to the map?

Comment: I am also open for solutions that dont use google maps heatmaplayer, I am just looking for a solution in how to create a map that shows me where the hotspots of locations are, in a way that I can analyze that data programmatically

Comment: I have solved the problem by manually saving points into a grid, thanks for the remarks nonetheless!